# Unwrap Googles snappedPoints in Swift

Tags: swift

I am getting a response from Google Roads API to get a bunch of snapped points to some coordinates however I am having trouble unwrapping the location item in the response.

The JSON I have is

```
snappedPoints =     (
{
location =     {
    latitude = "-37.74918160193682";
    longitude = "144.8963397730159";
};
originalIndex = 13;
placeId = "ChIJIb-jFGtc1moRMM8z7HRWBBM";
}, {
location =     {
    latitude = "-37.7491638";
    longitude = "144.8961793";
};
placeId = "ChIJIb-jFGtc1moRMM8z7HRWBBM";
},
...
```

I want to be able to access each latitude and longitude.

```
let jsonResult:AnyObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil)!
let snappedPoints = jsonResult["snappedPoints"] as! [NSDictionary]

for snappedPoint in snappedPoints {
    println(snappedPoint["placeId"])
    println(snappedPoint["location"])
}
```

I can get the placeID and even the location as an Optional but not sure how I can get and use the lat and long values.

Thanks

Comment: I think you can just cast the value of the location key as a dictionary again and pull out each value by it's key.

Comment: Thanks. Tried and getting Could not cast value of type '__NSCFDictionary'  to 'NSArray' error

Comment: I was just dealing with something like this, maybe cast the location to an array and then it's first value as a dictionary (or just print it and see what it contains).

Comment: From what I see is that location is a dictionary only, not an array!.